# Can I add a ServiceInstall component in a WiX installer that references a FileId in another component

Tags: wix, windows-services, installation

I have an installer that uses HEAT to harvest files from different places to create various components for the installer.

One of the components installs the files for a Windows Service.
I want to add another component that installs the service itself, but if I put the EXE file in the component, I am getting an error that the file would be installed twice.

Is there a way I can create a ServiceInstall component, but rather than add a File element, reference the ID of a file from another component?
I want to keep the option of installing the files but NOT installing the service.

Also, if I had to take the file out of the component it is in at the moment, it would add all sorts of complexity to the harvesting script.

The component section looks like this at the moment:

```
<Component Id='UtilServiceInstall' Guid='{2B244D6C-BEC3-471f-A0FB-5E3B729EBE56}'>
  <File Id='UtilityService' Name='UtilityService.exe' Source='UtilityService.exe' DiskId='1' KeyPath='yes' />
  <ServiceInstall Id="UtilService" Type="ownProcess" Name="UtilService" DisplayName="Utility Service" Description="Utility Service" Start="demand" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal">
  <util:PermissionEx  User="Everyone" ServicePauseContinue="yes" ServiceQueryStatus="yes" ServiceStart="yes" ServiceStop="yes" ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes" />                                
  </ServiceInstall>
  <ServiceControl Id="UtilService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Name="UtilService" Wait="no" />                                
</Component>
```

Comment: Same problem when you install a service, but want to decide somewhere in GUI whether it is manual or auto-start one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a requirement of ServiceInstall that the installed service is the KeyPath of the component, so you can't have the service be a file in another component.

You could create two separate components that are mutually exclusive, one with just the file and the other with the file installed as a service, and choose whichever is required.  You shouldn't get an error for two mutually exclusive components, that surprises me.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case (about the KeyPath). I haven't tried making the two components mutually exclusive (never even thought of that), but I will give it a try.

Comment: You cannot install same file by two different components, so this solution doesn't really work.

Comment: @Cavalier - that is not correct. The same file can be installed from two separate components if they have mutually exclusive conditions. It's always been allowed - even Microsoft used to do it with the old ATL merge module, one atl.dll conditioned on Version9X, the other on VersionNT.